# Spring interceptor not invoked

Tags: spring, resteasy

I am using spring and resteasy integration for exposing some REST based services. I am planning to use interceptors for logging and authentication but facing issues with interceptor invocation.

Controller class (using @Path for rest services)

```
@Controller
@Path("/v1.0/create")
public class ContollerClass{

@POST
@Path("/artifact")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public String someMethod(SampleVO sampleVO,@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
// Some functionality
}
```

acctrest-servlet.xml :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.comp.abc.xyz" />
<import resource="classpath:springmvc-resteasy.xml" />
<mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.comp.abc.xyz.interceptor.AuthenticationInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Interceptor :

```
 public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {


public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1,
        Object arg2) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("pre handle ************************");
    log.info("before handler execution");
    String requestID = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
    log.debug("request ID is  {} :: ", requestID);
    return true;
}
```

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>acctrest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>acctrest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Except the interceptor invocation, rest of the flow is working fine.

Comment: Your controller isn't a controller it is a rest easy bean. So spring isn't involved in it's invocation and as such an interceptor will not be invoked.

Comment: Thank you. Are resteasy interceptors only way to go forward in this case?